# R: Creating a dataframe with scraped data from RSelenium

Tags: r, rvest, rselenium

I'm scraping some information from Google Books (doing research on NHL teams), and I'm using `RSelenium` to get started:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(RSelenium) # using Docker
library(rvest)
library(httr)

remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4445L, browserName = "chrome")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("https://books.google.com/")
books <- remDr$findElement(using = "css", "[name = 'q']")
books$sendKeysToElement(list("NHL teams", key = "enter"))
bookElem <- remDr$findElements(using = "xpath",
                           "//h3[@class = 'LC20lb']//parent::a")

links <- sapply(bookElem, function(bookElem){
  bookElem$getElementAttribute("href")
})
```

The above navigates to the correct page and searches for "NHL teams." The one caveat, though, is that some of these books have a "preview" page, and to get to the meat (title, author, etc.), one has to make one click further, on "About this book":

```
for(link in links) {
  remDr$navigate(link)

  # If statement to get past book previews
  if (str_detect(link, "frontcover")) {

    # Finding elements for "About this book"
    link2 <- remDr$findElements(using = 'xpath', 
                                '//a[@id="sidebar-atb-link" and span[.="About this book"]]')

    # Clicking on the "About this book" links
    link2_about <- sapply(link2, function(link2){
      link2$getElementAttribute('href') 
    })

    duh <- map(link2_about, read_html)

    # NHL book title, author
    nhl_title <- duh %>% 
      map(html_nodes, '#bookinfo > h1 > span.fn > span') %>% 
      map_chr(html_text) %>% 
      print()

    author1 <- duh %>% 
      map(html_nodes, '#bookinfo div:nth-child(1) span') %>% 
      map_chr(html_text) %>% 
      print()

    test_df <- cbind(nhl_title, author1) # ONLY binds the last book/author
    print(test_df)

  } else {          
    print("lol you thought this would work?") # haven't built this part out yet             
  }
}
```

My use of `map` prints off individual titles/authors, and I can't figure out how to get them into a dataframe. Every time I use `tibble()` or `map_dfr()` I get errors. The `for` loop above lists the title and then author, but doesn't put anything together. How do I bind this all together into one frame?

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, what you want is a web crawler, which lets you get URLs then visit each of those URLs to get information from each. I've only done this in Python, but the [`Rcrawler`](https://github.com/salimk/Rcrawler) package seems similar that and is well documented

Comment: I think that's probably the route I will take... makes way more sense than what I've done above. But this inability to create a simple dataframe in the example above has become my personal boogeyman. Any insights on that would be appreciated, or some other cathartic advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer turned out to be quite simple. I simply had to add a blank list above the `for` loop, and then add that inside the loop. Eg,

```
blank_list <- list()

for(link in links) {
....

  blank_list[[link]] <- tibble(nhl_title, author1)
  wow <- bind_rows(blank_list) 
  print(wow)

}
```

Don't use `do.call()`, or other options, `bind_rows()` is simply quicker than the rest.